# Permission problems when accessing symlinks via sftp and scp on Windows Server 2019 with OpenSSH

Tags: openssh, symbolic-link, sftp, windows-server-2019, mklink

I set up OpenSSH on a Windows Server 2019 machine and now I'm able to access the machine via ssh from my Windows 10 client.

Then I created a folder on the Windows Server which contains several symbolic links to other local and remote paths and set the user as chrootdirectory for a user. When I access the folder with the user via sftp I can open the symlinks (to both local and remote paths) and see all the folders and files at the target of the symlinks. But as soon as I try to read a file I get the following error: `open for read: permission denied`

The strange thing is that I am able to create new files at the symlink targets but cannot read the file I just created afterwards.

I enabled symlinkevaluation for all directions on the Windows server:

```
fsutil behavior query symlinkevaluation
    Local to local symbolic links are enabled.
    Local to remote symbolic links are enabled.
    Remote to local symbolic links are enabled.
    Remote to remote symbolic links are enabled.
```

What really troubles me is that if I connect to the server via a ssh in putty with the same user I was using for sftp, I am able to read the same file without any problems. In this case I am not able to list the folder content with "dir":

```
user@server e:\sftp\symlink>more test.txt
This is a testfile.

user@server e:\sftp\symlink>dir
Access is denied.
```

Can anybody point me in a direction what to try next?

Best regards
Johannes